# Connect network adapter at Power on Virtual Machine vmware - possible conflict

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ip-address, vmware, nic

just a simple question:
I want to clone a VM (Vmware 6 environment), but I am scared of possible network conflicts on IP.
The machine I will use to clone is in WORKGROUP and not in domain.

If I am right everything will be just fine: I power on the new machine and nothing bad happens. Then I will change network settings on computer management to get a Static IP under my domain.

Please let me know, thanks

Marcello

Comment: Why are you using statically configured network addressing? That simply doesn't scale.

Comment: This is not the point of the question. I don't want it in DHCP

Comment: I don't think you read my question. I understand that you want to statically configure the network addressing. I asked, "Why?"

Comment: I have a rule on my firewall so I need to use a certain range of IP

Comment: But why can't you do that with DHCP? That solves your cloning problem, and you can reserve addresses in DHCP for particular hosts.

Comment: You can create a different DHCP scope for these VMs. You can have multiple DHCP scopes on the same network, or a scope on a different network if these devices are on a different network. You really are trying to do things the hard way.

Comment: Let's say you need to drive a nail. You have a hammer, screwdriver, wrench, and pliers, but you seem to want to use anything but the hammer to drive the nail. You should use the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the word "WORKGROUP", I assume that GuestOS is windows. As you think, bad things will not happen.

When the new machine starts up and assigns an IP address, the new machine performs ARP checks for a duplicate IP address. Of course, since the copy source machine uses the same IP address, the new machine detects it and assigns itself 0.0.0.0 or APIPA (depending on Windows setting).

Still, if you feel afraid, it is a good idea to uncheck  "Connect at power on" of the "Network Adapter" in VM properties before starting the new machine. After changing the IP address, you should check  "Connect at power on".